# What is the use of Critical Discourse Analysis Theory?

Tags: theoretical-linguistics, pragmatics, discourse-analysis, discourse

Can Critical Discourse Analysis be used to analyse the speech acts in a given Speech, and simply interpret the different orientations that those Speech acts impose upon that Speech (like joy, proudness ect...)
Or is Critical Discourse Analysis theory exclusively used to study power, structure, manipulation...?

Comment: By definition, this an enterprise that concerns social issues/society. Joy and degree of pride can only be ascertained through context. They are not intrinsically linguistic.  They come from intonation, for example, which is suprasegmental generally. Discourse analysis comes out more on the side of sociolinguistics. I will probably write and answer to this later. Right now, I am going to escape the heat where I am by going to the beach.